glassfish AccessDeniedException
I am new to using servers in general.
I am on Windows 11.
I just downloaded glassfish7 from https://glassfish.org/download.html
I then unziped it and ran the command ./asadmin start-domain
at C:\Program Files\Glassfish\glassfish7\bin
I got this error message:
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Glassfish\glassfish7\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:119)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:309)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:369)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:512)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:342)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:306)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:225)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:128)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:322)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:259)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:32)
Waiting for domain1 to start ............................................................
Waiting finished after 60,000 ms.
No response from the Domain Administration Server (domain1) after 60 seconds.
The command is either taking too long to complete or the server has failed.
Please see the server log files for command status.
Please start with the --verbose option in order to see early messages.
Command start-domain failed.

The \domains\domain1\logs directory is completely empty.

It looks like GlassFish doesn't have permissions to create the file \domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck. Did you run GlassFish with the same user which owns the GlassFish installation? Can you check if you can create a file in \domains\domain1\logs\ manually?
